# use of Indefinite Article

Tags: indefinite-article, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I have doubt about use of article in below sentence.

> **A cake is necessary when you have party.**

Does sentence uses correct article?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to precede "party" with the article "a" or change "party" to "parties."

Any one of the sentences below is correct:

> A cake is necessary for a party.
>
> A cake is necessary for parties.
>
> Cakes are necessary for parties

Personally, I prefer the first or third versions.

Comment: that is problem with the phrase "when you have party"

Comment: @raghav Yes, just modify your own sentence in the same way. Add *a* before *party*, turn *party* into *parties*, or start the sentence with *cakes are* as well as using *parties* at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Parties are countable. The word "party" refers to the entire duration of the party. So if you have a party that starts at 2 and ends at 6, the whole duration from 2-6 is one party. You can have one party, two parties, three parties, etc.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to say

> A cake is necessary when you have party

but it does make sense to say

> A cake is necessary when you have a party

By contrast, when you use the word "dirt", you aren't specifying exactly where the dirt begins and where the dirt ends.

It makes sense to say

> There is dirt on the floor

But it doesn't make sense to say

> There is a dirt on the floor

English speakers will not know where exactly "a" dirt starts or where "a" dirt ends. If you gave a person a picture of some dirt and you asked them to draw a circle around only one of the dirts, they would be very confused. Whereas they could tell you that a party began at 2 and ended at 6.

Cakes are also countable, so you are correct when you say "A cake".

There are other small grammatical mistakes in your question. It should be:

> Use of the Indefinite Article
>
> I have doubts about the use of articles in the below sentence
>
> > A cake is necessary when you have a party
>
> Does the sentence use the correct article?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. i have never thought party as countable noun